# Member of nested structure being somehow attached to the previous member of structure

Tags: c, nested, structure

I've got a problem with a nested structure. Program initializes array of structures where one member of structure is another structure. The program checks if the second name was given and presents full data in form

```
`Last_name, First name, (First character of the second name if it had been given). -- number
```

The problem is that I don't know why but somehow first name is being added to the end of PESEL member and as an output we are getting

```
Jordan, Michael J. -- 65092301159Michael
T, Thomas -- 98501233151Thomas
Christie, Agatha S. -- 25941325923Agatha
```

instead of

```
Jordan, Michael J. -- 65092301159
T, Thomas -- 98501233151
Christie, Agatha S. -- 25941325923
```

Here is a code, it uses C99 for designated initialization feature:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE1 11
#define SIZE2 81
#define N 3
struct person
{
    char name[SIZE2];
    char second_name[SIZE2];
    char last_name[SIZE2];
};
struct one
{
    char PESEL[SIZE1];
    struct person data;
};
void show(struct one *, int);
int main(void)
{
    struct one personal_data[N] = 
    {
    {
        "65092301159", 
        {
        "Michael",
        "James",
        "Jordan"
        }
    },
    {
        "98501233151",
        {
        .name = "Thomas",
        .last_name = "T"
        }
    },
    {
        "25941325923",
        {
        "Agatha",
        "Sam",
        "Christie"
        }
    }
    };
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
    if(strlen(personal_data[i].data.second_name) != 0)
        show(&personal_data[i], 1);
    else
        show(&personal_data[i], 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
void show(struct one *pt, int flag)
{
    if(flag)
    printf("%s, %s %c. -- %s\n",pt->data.last_name, pt->data.name, pt->data.second_name[0] , pt->PESEL);
    else
    printf("%s, %s -- %s\n",pt->data.last_name, pt->data.name , pt->PESEL);
}
```

Comment: sizeof("65092301159") is 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The size of `PELSEL` is 11 characters, and you're putting strings with 11 visible characters in it at initialization. This isn't leaving room for a null terminator[1] (`'\0'`), causing all the C string functions to overrun until they hit a char with value `'\0'` in memory, which happens to be the end of the first name (though if you had an 81-character first name, it very well could overrun further, possibly into protected memory crashing your program in an extreme case). Increasing `SIZE2` to 12 should fix this.

Remember: C strings always require a section of memory at least one bigger than the actual visible character count.

[1] Strictly speaking, it's actually writing the null terminator in the space reserved for the first character of the first name, and then immediately overwriting it when it writes the first name field. Fairly harmless in this case, but could be very harmful in less fortunate struct layouts.

Comment: "*Fairly harmless in this case ...*" but still provoking undefined behaviuor. Not nice.

Answer (score 4):

You put a name which overflows the buffer of size `11 * sizeof(char)`, so you have to increase the buffer size to avoid these type of problem.

The number of characters put need to be smaller than the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

The C style string ends with a `\0` character. When you use use printf("%s",..) to print out the value of a string, it will print out the characters one by one until it meet a '\0' character.

Because your struct type is POD type, that means the members of the struct is placed sequentially in the memory. Your nested class's memory model is:

```
char PESEL[11]] -> char name[81] -> char second_name[81]...
```

The name[81] is adjacent to the PESEL[11] string. So when you print PESEL, it is basically like:

```
char * c= pt->PESEL;
while(*c != '\0')
{
    printf("%c",*c);
    c++;
}
```

In your case, you only assign 11 bytes to PESEL. THe '\0' character used to seperate PESEL and name will be covered by the name's first character. And the upper process will not stop until it runs to the '\0' character of name variable. That's why your program print out extra name after PESEL.

which means you can put 10 characters into  the array **AT MOST** but not 11. You need to change `#define SIZE1 11` to `#define SIZE1 12`, all will be set.

Comment: Minor nitpick: C-style *strings* end with a `\0`. Nothing says you need to have a *char array* end with `\0`. It's perfectly valid to have a char array with no null terminator if you just want an array of bytes for whatever reason (and there are plenty of good ones, like a `char [4]` to encode truecolor RGBA values). It only matters if you intend to treat it as a string (i.e. use strcat, "%s", strcpy, etc).

Comment: @Jsor yeah, it only matters when your functions are based on this null terminator. :)

Comment: @richard.g: Why not add this (significant) addtion to your answer?